# Torch, why is my artificial neural network predicting always zeros?

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I'm working with Torch7 on Linux CentOS 7 machine.
I'm trying to apply a **artificial neural network (ANN)** to my dataset, to solve a **binary classification problem**. I'm using a simple **multi-layer perceptron**.

I'm using the following Torch packages: optim, torch.

The issue is that my **perceptron always predicts zero values** (elements classified as zeros), and I cannot understand why...

Here's my dataset ("dataset_file.csv"). There are 34 features and 1 label target (the last column, that might be 0 or 1):

```
0.55,1,0,1,0,0.29,1,0,1,0.46,1,1,0,0.67,1,0.37,0.41,1,0.08,0.47,0.23,0.13,0.82,0.46,0.25,0.04,0,0,0.52,1,0,0,0,0.33,0
0.65,1,0,1,0,0.64,1,0,0,0.02,1,1,1,1,0,0.52,0.32,0,0.18,0.67,0.47,0.2,0.64,0.38,0.23,1,0.24,0.18,0.04,1,1,1,1,0.41,0
0.34,1,0.13,1,0,0.33,0,0.5,0,0.02,0,0,0,0.67,1,0.25,0.55,1,0.06,0.23,0.18,0.15,0.82,0.51,0.22,0.06,0,0,0.6,1,0,0,0,0.42,1
0.46,1,0,1,0,0.14,1,0,0,0.06,0,1,1,0,1,0.37,0.64,1,0.14,0.22,0.17,0.1,0.94,0.65,0.22,0.06,0.75,0.64,0.3,1,1,0,0,0.2,0
0.55,1,0,1,0,0.14,1,0.5,1,0.03,1,1,0,1,1,0.42,0.18,0,0.16,0.55,0.16,0.12,0.73,0.55,0.2,0.03,0.54,0.44,0.35,1,1,0,0,0.11,0
0.67,1,0,1,0,0.71,0,0.5,0,0.46,1,0,1,1,1,0.74,0.41,0,0.1,0.6,0.15,0.15,0.69,0.42,0.27,0.04,0.61,0.48,0.54,1,1,0,0,0.22,1
0.52,1,0,1,0,0.21,1,0.5,0,0.01,1,1,1,0.67,0,0.27,0.64,0,0.08,0.34,0.14,0.21,0.85,0.51,0.2,0.05,0.51,0.36,0.36,1,1,0,0,0.23,0
0.58,1,0.38,1,0,0.36,1,0.5,1,0.02,0,1,0,1,1,0.38,0.55,1,0.13,0.57,0.21,0.23,0.73,0.52,0.19,0.03,0,0,0.6,1,0,0,0,0.42,0
0.66,1,0,1,0,0.07,1,0,0,0.06,1,0,0,1,1,0.24,0.32,1,0.06,0.45,0.16,0.13,0.92,0.57,0.27,0.06,0,0,0.55,1,0,0,0,0.33,0
0.39,1,0.5,1,0,0.29,1,0,1,0.06,0,0,0,1,1,0.34,0.45,1,0.1,0.31,0.12,0.16,0.81,0.54,0.21,0.02,0.51,0.27,0.5,1,1,0,0,0.32,0
0.26,0,0,1,0,0.21,1,0,0,0.02,1,1,1,0,1,0.17,0.36,0,0.19,0.41,0.24,0.26,0.73,0.55,0.22,0.41,0.46,0.43,0.42,1,1,0,0,0.52,0
0.96,0,0.63,1,0,0.86,1,0,1,0.06,1,1,1,0,0,0.41,0.5,1,0.08,0.64,0.23,0.19,0.69,0.45,0.23,0.06,0.72,0.43,0.45,1,1,0,0,0.53,0
0.58,0,0.25,1,0,0.29,1,0,1,0.04,1,0,0,0,1,0.4,0.27,1,0.09,0.65,0.21,0.16,0.8,0.57,0.24,0.02,0.51,0.28,0.5,1,1,1,0,0.63,0
0.6,1,0.5,1,0,0.73,1,0.5,1,0.04,1,0,1,0,1,0.85,0.64,1,0.16,0.71,0.24,0.21,0.72,0.45,0.23,0.1,0.63,0.57,0.13,1,1,1,1,0.65,0
0.72,1,0.25,1,0,0.29,1,0,0,0.06,1,0,0,1,1,0.31,0.41,1,0.17,0.78,0.24,0.16,0.75,0.54,0.27,0.09,0.78,0.68,0.19,1,1,1,1,0.75,0
0.56,0,0.13,1,0,0.4,1,0,0,0.23,1,0,0,1,1,0.42,1,0,0.03,0.14,0.15,0.13,0.85,0.52,0.24,0.06,0,0,0.56,1,0,0,0,0.33,0
0.67,0,0,1,0,0.57,1,0,1,0.02,0,0,0,1,1,0.38,0.36,0,0.08,0.12,0.11,0.14,0.8,0.49,0.22,0.05,0,0,0.6,1,0,0,0,0.22,0
0.67,0,0,1,0,0.36,1,0,0,0.23,0,1,0,0,0,0.32,0.73,0,0.25,0.86,0.26,0.16,0.62,0.35,0.25,0.02,0.46,0.43,0.45,1,1,1,0,0.76,0
0.55,1,0.5,1,0,0.57,0,0.5,1,0.12,1,1,1,0.67,1,1,0.45,0,0.19,0.94,0.19,0.22,0.88,0.41,0.35,0.15,0.47,0.4,0.05,1,1,1,0,0.56,1
0.61,0,0,1,0,0.43,1,0.5,1,0.04,1,0,1,0,0,0.68,0.23,1,0.12,0.68,0.25,0.29,0.68,0.45,0.29,0.13,0.58,0.41,0.11,1,1,1,1,0.74,0
0.59,1,0.25,1,0,0.23,1,0.5,0,0.02,1,1,1,0,1,0.57,0.41,1,0.08,0.05,0.16,0.15,0.87,0.61,0.25,0.04,0.67,0.61,0.45,1,1,0,0,0.65,0
0.74,1,0.5,1,0,0.26,1,0,1,0.01,1,1,1,1,0,0.76,0.36,0,0.14,0.72,0.12,0.13,0.68,0.54,0.54,0.17,0.93,0.82,0.12,1,1,0,0,0.18,0
0.64,0,0,1,0,0.29,0,0,1,0.15,0,0,1,0,1,0.33,0.45,0,0.11,0.55,0.25,0.15,0.75,0.54,0.27,0.05,0.61,0.64,0.43,1,1,0,0,0.23,1
0.36,0,0.38,1,0,0.14,0,0.5,0,0.02,1,1,1,0.33,1,0.18,0.36,0,0.17,0.79,0.21,0.12,0.75,0.54,0.24,0.05,0,0,0.52,1,0,0,0,0.44,1
0.52,0,0.75,1,0,0.14,1,0.5,0,0.04,1,1,1,0,1,0.36,0.68,1,0.08,0.34,0.12,0.13,0.79,0.59,0.22,0.02,0,0,0.5,1,0,0,0,0.23,0
0.59,0,0.75,1,0,0.29,1,0,0,0.06,1,1,0,0,1,0.24,0.27,0,0.12,0.7,0.2,0.16,0.74,0.45,0.26,0.02,0.46,0.32,0.52,1,0,0,0,0.33,0
0.72,1,0.38,1,0,0.43,0,0.5,0,0.06,1,0,1,0.67,1,0.53,0.32,0,0.2,0.68,0.16,0.13,0.79,0.45,0.25,0.09,0.61,0.57,0.15,1,1,0,0,0.22,1
```

And here's my Torch Lua code:

```
-- add comma to separate thousands
function comma_value(amount)
  local formatted = amount
  while true do  
    formatted, k = string.gsub(formatted, "^(-?%d+)(%d%d%d)", '%1,%2')
    if (k==0) then
      break
    end
  end
  return formatted
end

-- function that computes the confusion matrix
function confusion_matrix(predictionTestVect, truthVect, threshold, printValues)

  local tp = 0
  local tn = 0
  local fp = 0
  local fn = 0
  local MatthewsCC = -2
  local accuracy = -2
  local arrayFPindices = {}
  local arrayFPvalues = {}
  local arrayTPvalues = {}
  local areaRoc = 0

  local fpRateVett = {}
  local tpRateVett = {}
  local precisionVett = {}
  local recallVett = {}

  for i=1,#predictionTestVect do

    if printValues == true then
      io.write("predictionTestVect["..i.."] = ".. round(predictionTestVect[i],4).."\ttruthVect["..i.."] = "..truthVect[i].." ");
      io.flush();
    end

    if predictionTestVect[i] >= threshold and truthVect[i] >= threshold then
      tp = tp + 1
      arrayTPvalues[#arrayTPvalues+1] = predictionTestVect[i]
      if printValues == true then print(" TP ") end
    elseif  predictionTestVect[i] < threshold and truthVect[i] >= threshold then
      fn = fn + 1
      if printValues == true then print(" FN ") end
    elseif  predictionTestVect[i] >= threshold and truthVect[i] < threshold then
      fp = fp + 1
      if printValues == true then print(" FP ") end
      arrayFPindices[#arrayFPindices+1] = i;
      arrayFPvalues[#arrayFPvalues+1] = predictionTestVect[i]  
    elseif  predictionTestVect[i] < threshold and truthVect[i] < threshold then
      tn = tn + 1
      if printValues == true then print(" TN ") end
    end
  end

    print("TOTAL:")
    print(" FN = "..comma_value(fn).." / "..comma_value(tonumber(fn+tp)).."\t (truth == 1) & (prediction < threshold)");
    print(" TP = "..comma_value(tp).." / "..comma_value(tonumber(fn+tp)).."\t (truth == 1) & (prediction >= threshold)\n");

    print(" FP = "..comma_value(fp).." / "..comma_value(tonumber(fp+tn)).."\t (truth == 0) & (prediction >= threshold)");
    print(" TN = "..comma_value(tn).." / "..comma_value(tonumber(fp+tn)).."\t (truth == 0) & (prediction < threshold)\n");

  local continueLabel = true

    if continueLabel then
      upperMCC = (tp*tn) - (fp*fn)
      innerSquare = (tp+fp)*(tp+fn)*(tn+fp)*(tn+fn)
      lowerMCC = math.sqrt(innerSquare)

      MatthewsCC = -2
      if lowerMCC>0 then MatthewsCC = upperMCC/lowerMCC end
      local signedMCC = MatthewsCC
      print("signedMCC = "..signedMCC)

      if MatthewsCC > -2 then print("\n::::\tMatthews correlation coefficient = "..signedMCC.."\t::::\n");
      else print("Matthews correlation coefficient = NOT computable");  end

      accuracy = (tp + tn)/(tp + tn +fn + fp)
      print("accuracy = "..round(accuracy,2).. " = (tp + tn) / (tp + tn +fn + fp) \t  \t [worst = -1, best =  +1]");

      local f1_score = -2
      if (tp+fp+fn)>0 then   
    f1_score = (2*tp) / (2*tp+fp+fn)
    print("f1_score = "..round(f1_score,2).." = (2*tp) / (2*tp+fp+fn) \t [worst = 0, best = 1]");
      else
    print("f1_score CANNOT be computed because (tp+fp+fn)==0")    
      end

      local totalRate = 0
      if MatthewsCC > -2 and f1_score > -2 then 
    totalRate = MatthewsCC + accuracy + f1_score 
    print("total rate = "..round(totalRate,2).." in [-1, +3] that is "..round((totalRate+1)*100/4,2).."% of possible correctness");
      end

      local numberOfPredictedOnes = tp + fp;
      print("numberOfPredictedOnes = (TP + FP) = "..comma_value(numberOfPredictedOnes).." = "..round(numberOfPredictedOnes*100/(tp + tn + fn + fp),2).."%");

      io.write("\nDiagnosis: ");
      if (fn >= tp and (fn+tp)>0) then print("too many FN false negatives"); end
      if (fp >= tn and (fp+tn)>0) then print("too many FP false positives"); end


      if (tn > (10*fp) and tp > (10*fn)) then print("Excellent ! ! !");
      elseif (tn > (5*fp) and tp > (5*fn)) then print("Very good ! !"); 
      elseif (tn > (2*fp) and tp > (2*fn)) then print("Good !"); 
      elseif (tn >= fp and tp >= fn) then print("Alright"); 
      else print("Baaaad"); end
    end

    return {accuracy, arrayFPindices, arrayFPvalues, MatthewsCC};
end


-- Permutations
-- tab = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
-- permute(tab, 10, 10)
function permute(tab, n, count)
      n = n or #tab
      for i = 1, count or n do
        local j = math.random(i, n)
        tab[i], tab[j] = tab[j], tab[i]
      end
      return tab
end

-- round a real value
function round(num, idp)
  local mult = 10^(idp or 0)
  return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end



-- ##############################3

local profile_vett = {}
local csv = require("csv")
local fileName = "dataset_file.csv" 

print("Readin' "..tostring(fileName))
local f = csv.open(fileName)
local column_names = {}

local j = 0
for fields in f:lines() do

  if j>0 then
    profile_vett[j] = {}
      for i, v in ipairs(fields) do 
    profile_vett[j][i] = tonumber(v);
      end
    j = j + 1
  else
    for i, v in ipairs(fields) do 
    column_names[i] = v
     end
    j = j + 1
  end
end

OPTIM_PACKAGE = true
local output_number = 1
THRESHOLD = 0.5 -- ORIGINAL
DROPOUT_FLAG = false
MOMENTUM = false
MOMENTUM_ALPHA = 0.5
MAX_MSE = 4
LEARN_RATE = 0.001
ITERATIONS = 100

local hidden_units = 2000
local hidden_layers = 1

local hiddenUnitVect = {2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000}
-- local hiddenLayerVect = {1,2,3,4,5}
local hiddenLayerVect = {1}

local profile_vett_data = {}
local label_vett = {}

for i=1,#profile_vett do
  profile_vett_data[i] = {}

  for j=1,#(profile_vett[1]) do  
    if j<#(profile_vett[1]) then
      profile_vett_data[i][j] = profile_vett[i][j]
    else
      label_vett[i] = profile_vett[i][j]
    end    
  end
end

print("Number of value profiles (rows) = "..#profile_vett_data);
print("Number features (columns) = "..#(profile_vett_data[1]));
print("Number of targets (rows) = "..#label_vett);

local table_row_outcome = label_vett
local table_rows_vett = profile_vett

-- ########################################################

-- START

local indexVect = {}; 
for i=1, #table_rows_vett do indexVect[i] = i;  end
permutedIndexVect = permute(indexVect, #indexVect, #indexVect);

TEST_SET_PERC = 20
local test_set_size = round((TEST_SET_PERC*#table_rows_vett)/100)

print("training_set_size = "..(#table_rows_vett-test_set_size).." elements");
print("test_set_size = "..test_set_size.." elements\n");

local train_table_row_profile = {}
local test_table_row_profile = {}
local original_test_indexes = {}

for i=1,#table_rows_vett do
  if i<=(tonumber(#table_rows_vett)-test_set_size) then
    train_table_row_profile[#train_table_row_profile+1] = {torch.Tensor(table_rows_vett[permutedIndexVect[i]]), torch.Tensor{table_row_outcome[permutedIndexVect[i]]}}
  else

    original_test_indexes[#original_test_indexes+1] = permutedIndexVect[i];

    test_table_row_profile[#test_table_row_profile+1] = {torch.Tensor(table_rows_vett[permutedIndexVect[i]]), torch.Tensor{table_row_outcome[permutedIndexVect[i]]}}
  end
end

require 'nn'
perceptron = nn.Sequential()
input_number = #table_rows_vett[1]

perceptron:add(nn.Linear(input_number, hidden_units))
perceptron:add(nn.Sigmoid())
if DROPOUT_FLAG==true then perceptron:add(nn.Dropout()) end

for w=1,hidden_layers do
  perceptron:add(nn.Linear(hidden_units, hidden_units))
  perceptron:add(nn.Sigmoid())
  if DROPOUT_FLAG==true then perceptron:add(nn.Dropout()) end
end
perceptron:add(nn.Linear(hidden_units, output_number))


function train_table_row_profile:size() return #train_table_row_profile end 
function test_table_row_profile:size() return #test_table_row_profile end 


-- OPTIMIZATION LOOPS  
local MCC_vect = {}  

for a=1,#hiddenUnitVect do
  for b=1,#hiddenLayerVect do

    local hidden_units = hiddenUnitVect[a]
    local hidden_layers = hiddenLayerVect[b]
    print("hidden_units = "..hidden_units.."\t output_number = "..output_number.." hidden_layers = "..hidden_layers)


    local criterion = nn.MSECriterion()  
    local lossSum = 0
    local error_progress = 0

      require 'optim'
      local params, gradParams = perceptron:getParameters()     
      local optimState = nil

      if MOMENTUM==true then 
    optimState = {learningRate = LEARN_RATE}
      else 
    optimState = {learningRate = LEARN_RATE,
              momentum = MOMENTUM_ALPHA }
      end

      local total_runs = ITERATIONS*#train_table_row_profile

      local loopIterations = 1
      for epoch=1,ITERATIONS do
    for k=1,#train_table_row_profile do

        -- Function feval 
        local function feval(params)
        gradParams:zero()

        local thisProfile = train_table_row_profile[k][1]
        local thisLabel = train_table_row_profile[k][2]

        local thisPrediction = perceptron:forward(thisProfile)
        local loss = criterion:forward(thisPrediction, thisLabel)

        -- print("thisPrediction = "..round(thisPrediction[1],2).." thisLabel = "..thisLabel[1])

        lossSum = lossSum + loss
        error_progress = lossSum*100 / (loopIterations*MAX_MSE)

        if ((loopIterations*100/total_runs)*10)%10==0 then
          io.write("completion: ", round((loopIterations*100/total_runs),2).."%" )
          io.write(" (epoch="..epoch..")(element="..k..") loss = "..round(loss,2).." ")      
          io.write("\terror progress = "..round(error_progress,5).."%\n")
        end

        local dloss_doutput = criterion:backward(thisPrediction, thisLabel)

        perceptron:backward(thisProfile, dloss_doutput)

        return loss,gradParams
        end
      optim.sgd(feval, params, optimState)
      loopIterations = loopIterations+1
    end     
      end


    local correctPredictions = 0
    local atleastOneTrue = false
    local atleastOneFalse = false
    local predictionTestVect = {}
    local truthVect = {}

    for i=1,#test_table_row_profile do
      local current_label = test_table_row_profile[i][2][1]
      local prediction = perceptron:forward(test_table_row_profile[i][1])[1]

      predictionTestVect[i] = prediction
      truthVect[i] = current_label

      local labelResult = false

      if current_label >= THRESHOLD and prediction >= THRESHOLD  then
    labelResult = true
      elseif current_label < THRESHOLD and prediction < THRESHOLD  then
    labelResult = true
      end

      if labelResult==true then correctPredictions = correctPredictions + 1; end

    print("\nCorrect predictions = "..round(correctPredictions*100/#test_table_row_profile,2).."%")

     local printValues = false
     local output_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(predictionTestVect, truthVect, THRESHOLD, printValues)
  end
end
```

Does anyone have an idea about why my script is predicting only zero elements?

EDIT: I replaced the original dataset with its normalized version, that I use in my script

Comment: I'm not familiar with torch/lua but i can't find any data-normalization step within your code. Are you doing this? This is very important (especially because you got one column with huge values compared to the others)! You might also want to show some convergence numbers. Is the training error decreased?

Comment: @sascha Thanks, I'm using the normalized dataset actually, but I inserted the original dataset by accident. Now I replaced the original dataset with the normalized one. Thanks for noticing it. And yes, the training error decreases usually from ~15 to ~6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your original code I sometimes get all zeros predicted, and I sometimes get perfect performance. This suggests your original model is very sensitive to the initialization of the parameter values.

If I use a seed value of `torch.manualSeed(0)` (so we always have the same initialization) I get perfect performance every time. But this isn't really a general solution.

To get a more general improvement I have made the following changes:

1. Reduced the number of hidden units. In the original code you have a
   single hidden layer of `2000` units. But you only have 34 inputs and
   1 output Often you only need the number of hidden units to be
   between the number of inputs and outputs. I have reduced it to
   `50`.
2. The labels are asymmetric, only 5/27 (19%) of the labels are ones, so you should really divide the train|test sets in such a way that preserves the ratio of ones to zeros. For now I have simply increased the test set size to '50'%.
3. I have also increased the learning rate to '0.01', turned `MOMENTUM` on, and increased `ITERATIONS` to 200.

When I run this model 20 times (unseeded) I got `Excellent` performance 19 times. To improve further you could tweak the hyper-parameters further. And should also look at multiple initializations with a separate validation set to choose the "best" model (although this will further sub-divide your already very small data-set).

```
-- add comma to separate thousands
function comma_value(amount)
  local formatted = amount
  while true do  
    formatted, k = string.gsub(formatted, "^(-?%d+)(%d%d%d)", '%1,%2')
    if (k==0) then
      break
    end
  end
  return formatted
end

-- function that computes the confusion matrix
function confusion_matrix(predictionTestVect, truthVect, threshold, printValues)

  local tp = 0
  local tn = 0
  local fp = 0
  local fn = 0
  local MatthewsCC = -2
  local accuracy = -2
  local arrayFPindices = {}
  local arrayFPvalues = {}
  local arrayTPvalues = {}
  local areaRoc = 0

  local fpRateVett = {}
  local tpRateVett = {}
  local precisionVett = {}
  local recallVett = {}

  for i=1,#predictionTestVect do

    if printValues == true then
      io.write("predictionTestVect["..i.."] = ".. round(predictionTestVect[i],4).."\ttruthVect["..i.."] = "..truthVect[i].." ");
      io.flush();
    end

    if predictionTestVect[i] >= threshold and truthVect[i] >= threshold then
      tp = tp + 1
      arrayTPvalues[#arrayTPvalues+1] = predictionTestVect[i]
      if printValues == true then print(" TP ") end
    elseif  predictionTestVect[i] < threshold and truthVect[i] >= threshold then
      fn = fn + 1
      if printValues == true then print(" FN ") end
    elseif  predictionTestVect[i] >= threshold and truthVect[i] < threshold then
      fp = fp + 1
      if printValues == true then print(" FP ") end
      arrayFPindices[#arrayFPindices+1] = i;
      arrayFPvalues[#arrayFPvalues+1] = predictionTestVect[i]  
    elseif  predictionTestVect[i] < threshold and truthVect[i] < threshold then
      tn = tn + 1
      if printValues == true then print(" TN ") end
    end
  end

    print("TOTAL:")
    print(" FN = "..comma_value(fn).." / "..comma_value(tonumber(fn+tp)).."\t (truth == 1) & (prediction < threshold)");
    print(" TP = "..comma_value(tp).." / "..comma_value(tonumber(fn+tp)).."\t (truth == 1) & (prediction >= threshold)\n");

    print(" FP = "..comma_value(fp).." / "..comma_value(tonumber(fp+tn)).."\t (truth == 0) & (prediction >= threshold)");
    print(" TN = "..comma_value(tn).." / "..comma_value(tonumber(fp+tn)).."\t (truth == 0) & (prediction < threshold)\n");

  local continueLabel = true

    if continueLabel then
      upperMCC = (tp*tn) - (fp*fn)
      innerSquare = (tp+fp)*(tp+fn)*(tn+fp)*(tn+fn)
      lowerMCC = math.sqrt(innerSquare)

      MatthewsCC = -2
      if lowerMCC>0 then MatthewsCC = upperMCC/lowerMCC end
      local signedMCC = MatthewsCC
      print("signedMCC = "..signedMCC)

      if MatthewsCC > -2 then print("\n::::\tMatthews correlation coefficient = "..signedMCC.."\t::::\n");
      else print("Matthews correlation coefficient = NOT computable");  end

      accuracy = (tp + tn)/(tp + tn +fn + fp)
      print("accuracy = "..round(accuracy,2).. " = (tp + tn) / (tp + tn +fn + fp) \t  \t [worst = -1, best =  +1]");

      local f1_score = -2
      if (tp+fp+fn)>0 then   
    f1_score = (2*tp) / (2*tp+fp+fn)
    print("f1_score = "..round(f1_score,2).." = (2*tp) / (2*tp+fp+fn) \t [worst = 0, best = 1]");
      else
    print("f1_score CANNOT be computed because (tp+fp+fn)==0")    
      end

      local totalRate = 0
      if MatthewsCC > -2 and f1_score > -2 then 
    totalRate = MatthewsCC + accuracy + f1_score 
    print("total rate = "..round(totalRate,2).." in [-1, +3] that is "..round((totalRate+1)*100/4,2).."% of possible correctness");
      end

      local numberOfPredictedOnes = tp + fp;
      print("numberOfPredictedOnes = (TP + FP) = "..comma_value(numberOfPredictedOnes).." = "..round(numberOfPredictedOnes*100/(tp + tn + fn + fp),2).."%");

      io.write("\nDiagnosis: ");
      if (fn >= tp and (fn+tp)>0) then print("too many FN false negatives"); end
      if (fp >= tn and (fp+tn)>0) then print("too many FP false positives"); end


      if (tn > (10*fp) and tp > (10*fn)) then print("Excellent ! ! !");
      elseif (tn > (5*fp) and tp > (5*fn)) then print("Very good ! !"); 
      elseif (tn > (2*fp) and tp > (2*fn)) then print("Good !"); 
      elseif (tn >= fp and tp >= fn) then print("Alright"); 
      else print("Baaaad"); end
    end

    return {accuracy, arrayFPindices, arrayFPvalues, MatthewsCC};
end


-- Permutations
-- tab = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
-- permute(tab, 10, 10)
function permute(tab, n, count)
      n = n or #tab
      for i = 1, count or n do
        local j = math.random(i, n)
        tab[i], tab[j] = tab[j], tab[i]
      end
      return tab
end

-- round a real value
function round(num, idp)
  local mult = 10^(idp or 0)
  return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end



-- ##############################3

local profile_vett = {}
local csv = require("csv")
local fileName = "dataset_file.csv" 

print("Readin' "..tostring(fileName))
local f = csv.open(fileName)
local column_names = {}

local j = 0
for fields in f:lines() do

  if j>0 then
    profile_vett[j] = {}
      for i, v in ipairs(fields) do 
    profile_vett[j][i] = tonumber(v);
      end
    j = j + 1
  else
    for i, v in ipairs(fields) do 
    column_names[i] = v
     end
    j = j + 1
  end
end

OPTIM_PACKAGE = true
local output_number = 1
THRESHOLD = 0.5 -- ORIGINAL
DROPOUT_FLAG = false
MOMENTUM_ALPHA = 0.5
MAX_MSE = 4

-- CHANGE: increased learn_rate to 0.01, reduced hidden units to 50, turned momentum on, increased iterations to 200
LEARN_RATE = 0.01
local hidden_units = 50
MOMENTUM = true
ITERATIONS = 200
-------------------------------------

local hidden_layers = 1

local hiddenUnitVect = {2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000}
-- local hiddenLayerVect = {1,2,3,4,5}
local hiddenLayerVect = {1}

local profile_vett_data = {}
local label_vett = {}

for i=1,#profile_vett do
  profile_vett_data[i] = {}

  for j=1,#(profile_vett[1]) do  
    if j<#(profile_vett[1]) then
      profile_vett_data[i][j] = profile_vett[i][j]
    else
      label_vett[i] = profile_vett[i][j]
    end    
  end
end

print("Number of value profiles (rows) = "..#profile_vett_data);
print("Number features (columns) = "..#(profile_vett_data[1]));
print("Number of targets (rows) = "..#label_vett);

local table_row_outcome = label_vett
local table_rows_vett = profile_vett

-- ########################################################

-- START

-- Seed random number generator
-- torch.manualSeed(0)

local indexVect = {}; 
for i=1, #table_rows_vett do indexVect[i] = i;  end
permutedIndexVect = permute(indexVect, #indexVect, #indexVect);

-- CHANGE: increase test_set to 50%
TEST_SET_PERC = 50
---------------------------

local test_set_size = round((TEST_SET_PERC*#table_rows_vett)/100)

print("training_set_size = "..(#table_rows_vett-test_set_size).." elements");
print("test_set_size = "..test_set_size.." elements\n");

local train_table_row_profile = {}
local test_table_row_profile = {}
local original_test_indexes = {}

for i=1,#table_rows_vett do
  if i<=(tonumber(#table_rows_vett)-test_set_size) then
    train_table_row_profile[#train_table_row_profile+1] = {torch.Tensor(table_rows_vett[permutedIndexVect[i]]), torch.Tensor{table_row_outcome[permutedIndexVect[i]]}}
  else

    original_test_indexes[#original_test_indexes+1] = permutedIndexVect[i];

    test_table_row_profile[#test_table_row_profile+1] = {torch.Tensor(table_rows_vett[permutedIndexVect[i]]), torch.Tensor{table_row_outcome[permutedIndexVect[i]]}}
  end
end

require 'nn'
perceptron = nn.Sequential()
input_number = #table_rows_vett[1]

perceptron:add(nn.Linear(input_number, hidden_units))
perceptron:add(nn.Sigmoid())
if DROPOUT_FLAG==true then perceptron:add(nn.Dropout()) end

for w=1,hidden_layers do
  perceptron:add(nn.Linear(hidden_units, hidden_units))
  perceptron:add(nn.Sigmoid())
  if DROPOUT_FLAG==true then perceptron:add(nn.Dropout()) end
end
perceptron:add(nn.Linear(hidden_units, output_number))


function train_table_row_profile:size() return #train_table_row_profile end 
function test_table_row_profile:size() return #test_table_row_profile end 


-- OPTIMIZATION LOOPS  
local MCC_vect = {}  

for a=1,#hiddenUnitVect do
  for b=1,#hiddenLayerVect do

    local hidden_units = hiddenUnitVect[a]
    local hidden_layers = hiddenLayerVect[b]
    print("hidden_units = "..hidden_units.."\t output_number = "..output_number.." hidden_layers = "..hidden_layers)


    local criterion = nn.MSECriterion()  
    local lossSum = 0
    local error_progress = 0

      require 'optim'
      local params, gradParams = perceptron:getParameters()     
      local optimState = nil

      if MOMENTUM==true then 
    optimState = {learningRate = LEARN_RATE}
      else 
    optimState = {learningRate = LEARN_RATE,
              momentum = MOMENTUM_ALPHA }
      end

      local total_runs = ITERATIONS*#train_table_row_profile

      local loopIterations = 1
      for epoch=1,ITERATIONS do
    for k=1,#train_table_row_profile do

        -- Function feval 
        local function feval(params)
        gradParams:zero()

        local thisProfile = train_table_row_profile[k][1]
        local thisLabel = train_table_row_profile[k][2]

        local thisPrediction = perceptron:forward(thisProfile)
        local loss = criterion:forward(thisPrediction, thisLabel)

        -- print("thisPrediction = "..round(thisPrediction[1],2).." thisLabel = "..thisLabel[1])

        lossSum = lossSum + loss
        error_progress = lossSum*100 / (loopIterations*MAX_MSE)

        if ((loopIterations*100/total_runs)*10)%10==0 then
          io.write("completion: ", round((loopIterations*100/total_runs),2).."%" )
          io.write(" (epoch="..epoch..")(element="..k..") loss = "..round(loss,2).." ")      
          io.write("\terror progress = "..round(error_progress,5).."%\n")
        end

        local dloss_doutput = criterion:backward(thisPrediction, thisLabel)

        perceptron:backward(thisProfile, dloss_doutput)

        return loss,gradParams
        end
      optim.sgd(feval, params, optimState)
      loopIterations = loopIterations+1
    end     
      end


    local correctPredictions = 0
    local atleastOneTrue = false
    local atleastOneFalse = false
    local predictionTestVect = {}
    local truthVect = {}

    for i=1,#test_table_row_profile do
      local current_label = test_table_row_profile[i][2][1]
      local prediction = perceptron:forward(test_table_row_profile[i][1])[1]

      predictionTestVect[i] = prediction
      truthVect[i] = current_label

      local labelResult = false

      if current_label >= THRESHOLD and prediction >= THRESHOLD  then
    labelResult = true
      elseif current_label < THRESHOLD and prediction < THRESHOLD  then
    labelResult = true
      end

      if labelResult==true then correctPredictions = correctPredictions + 1; end

    print("\nCorrect predictions = "..round(correctPredictions*100/#test_table_row_profile,2).."%")

     local printValues = false
     local output_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(predictionTestVect, truthVect, THRESHOLD, printValues)
  end
end
end
```

Pasted below is the output of 1 of the 20 runs:

```
Correct predictions = 100%  
TOTAL:  
 FN = 0 / 4  (truth == 1) & (prediction < threshold)    
 TP = 4 / 4  (truth == 1) & (prediction >= threshold)

 FP = 0 / 9  (truth == 0) & (prediction >= threshold)   
 TN = 9 / 9  (truth == 0) & (prediction < threshold)

signedMCC = 1   

::::    Matthews correlation coefficient = 1    ::::

accuracy = 1 = (tp + tn) / (tp + tn +fn + fp)        [worst = -1, best =  +1]   
f1_score = 1 = (2*tp) / (2*tp+fp+fn)     [worst = 0, best = 1]  
total rate = 3 in [-1, +3] that is 100% of possible correctness 
numberOfPredictedOnes = (TP + FP) = 4 = 30.77%  

Diagnosis: Excellent ! ! !
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid, it really worked! Questions: how did you know that the hidden unit number should have been reduced to `50`?  How did you know that the learning rate should have been increased to `0.01`? How did you know that the iteration number should have been increased to `200`?

Comment: There is a good paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5533v2.pdf) with advice on hyper-parameter tuning, although I have to admit I have not yet had chance to read much of it. My thought process was to first make the network only as large as it needed to be (as mentioned in the question it is rare that a network needs to be more than twice the size (width) of the larger of the input/output layers). After that experimenting with the other parameters is quicker (as model trains faster).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your NN is learning too slow and thus not learning anything. Deeplearning4j has a great article on [troubleshooting neural net training](http://deeplearning4j.org/troubleshootingneuralnets), which may shed some light on the effect the various hyperparameters have.

Having had a glance at your code, I would first try the following things:

- **Adjust learning rate:**
  You have fixed the learn rate to: `LEARN_RATE = 0.001`. Try values between `1e-1` and `1e-8`.
- **Tweak your hidden layer:**
  You may have to tweak your hidden layer: `hiddenUnitVect = {2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000}`. This seems a little big for the task at hand. Try a smaller net first and increase the size if it does not generalize well.